# Is there a way to export the Cryptomatte "pick" image entirely?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, cryptomatte

I'm using the cryptomatte node to export individual mattes for various items in my renders, but I'd like to also export the entire "pick" image to a new file just as it's visible in the node graph interface with random colors and all:

[image: cryptomatte picker with random colors]

When I connect the "pick" image itself to a "file output" node I get an empty PNG saved to the drive, and I can't figure out a stack of nodes that will save it as an image.

My workaround would be to write a python script that runs through all of the objects in the scene, creates a cryptomatte node with a path export for each object, saves the file for each object to a folder, and then I merge all these files with opencv... but that's a little intense to recreate an image that's right there in Blender. I'm sure there's a better way! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after playing with this for a couple of days, the issue is related to this:
https://developer.blender.org/T101601

It seems to be specific to blender > 3.0 at the moment, and the behaviour varies depending on system architecture. On M1 Apple systems the results are also different depending on whether you use Cycles in GPU or CPU mode.

If I stick to Blender 3.3 using Cycles in GPU compute on Nvidia / Linux the issue doesn't appear for my scene, but it looks like there will be an update to the blender codebase in the near future to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

export as multilayer .exr

names have to be identical in the nodes